# How to Fix number of requests in JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I need to test performance of service with fixed number of requests with increasing threads. So, for example, -
I need to send 2000 requests with 4 threads, once 2000 requests are sent, then
send 2000 requests with 8 threads, then
send 2000 requests with 12 threads.

Meaning, step up should be done only after completing 2000 requests.

How can this be done in JMeter?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

None of JMeter's [test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) supports the configuration you want to setup.

The easiest would be setting the number of threads using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image]

once done you will be able to [run JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -Jthreads=4 -n -t testplan.jmx -l 4-threads.jtl
```

and

```
jmeter -Jthreads=8 -n -t testplan.jmx -l 8-threads.jtl
```

etc.

If you want to put all the results into a single file you can use [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin

Comment: Let me try this